# Error 550 when uploading files to server using filezilla

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, filezilla

I was uploading some changes to my server, when some file returned with an error 550.
I've send more than 500 files withou any problem, but this 14 files simply don't upload. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local "permissions error" or "file in use" error are the first two thoughts that occur to me...

See also:

- Make sure you're not trying to write to a network share using the Windows "System" account:

  [Filezilla error 550 trying to write files to a network share from the Windows "System" account](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=5559)
- Make sure you're not trying to write to a read-only file:

  [Configure Filezilla FTP Server to Allow Uploads](https://superuser.com/questions/811883/configure-filezilla-ftp-server-to-allow-uploads)

Answer (score 2):

Drive was full. Deleting some files solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching the web for a second and I've seen people having the same problem...

If you are using a Windows computer, here's the answer on how to fix this:
[Filezilla forum error 550](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=5559)

Otherwise, Be sure that your destination folder has the right permissions...

Comment: And this is what they said exactly...

Change the user for the service in the services dialog of the Windows control panel.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Filezilla FTP Server. I was facing problem with Error message 550 Could not open file for writing.

I have removed the directories where the files are downloading. Not physically from the Hard Disk / Storage Media. Just Logically from the FileZilla User Directories assigning options.

And again assign the same directories. Also kick the current Session of transferring files. By Right Click on a particular IP and then you can select the option kick user.

It will quit transferring and withing 1-2 minute it will start downloading files and error will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was able to resolve the problem on **CentOS 6.9** ISPConfig 3 VPS. It's related to the folder ownership issue.

Using **SSH**, check your folder and files by running `ls -l` ownership.

Make sure that the folder is owned by the user and has the correct group. To change folder permission use 
`chown -R web3:client4 /var/www/clients/client4/web3/web/`

More about `chown` commad [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchown.htm).